# What does "ワルよのぉ" mean?

Tags: translation

From here. https://renta.papy.co.jp/renta/sc/frm/item/153164/

> お主もワルよのぉ

Is this different in meaning from just "悪い”? Or is this something else entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「ワル」 is a colloquial word meaning "villain", "delinquent boy", etc.  It is pretty much synonymous to 「悪人{あくにん}」.

「よのう/よのお」 is a dramatic-sounding sentence-ender of exclamation.  It is synonymous to 「だねえ」 in meaning.

「お主{ぬし}」 just means "you".

> お主もワルよのぉ

thus means:

> "You are as shrewd/bad as I!"

The phrase is heard mostly in fiction and it is almost always said by a ワル to another of the same kind.  Hence, the 「も」.